# How to add, subtract, multiply, and divide in plain TeX?

Tags: plain-tex, calculations

I find many cases where I need to calculate many numbers, using adding, subtracting, multiplying, and dividing, but it would save much time if TeX could simply compute these for me.

This is a sample situation, which can calculate how many minutes or hours spend in lessons and how many of those minutes are spent in the laboratory.

```
\def\weeks{20} % term is twenty weeks
\def\lessonsperweek{3} % meets three times per week
\def\lessonduration{60} % meets for sixty minutes

\def\percentlectures{.5} % half the time is spent in lectures
\def\percentdiscussions{.2} % 20 percent of the time is spent in disucssions
\def\percentlab{1 - \percentdiscussions - \percentlectures} % remaining percent of time left to lab work

\def\totalduration{\lessonduration * \lessonsperweek * \weeks} % minutes spent in lessons

\def\totaldurationhours{\totalduration / 60}

\def\labduration{\totalduration * \percentlabs} % minutes spent in the lab

Total time in lab: \labduration minutes.

Total minutes in class: \totalduration minutes.

Total hours in class: \totaldurationhours hours.

\def\weeks{19} % these two values are changed later in the document
\def\lessonsperweek{2}

Total minutes in class: \totalduration minutes. % this value would be different because of the chagnes to \weeks and \lessonsperweek
```

When I compiled this, `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` were just displayed in the document as symbols. How can I let TeX calculate these values?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do arithmetic (with `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, but no `^` for powers) using  `\numexpr` expressions.

The `\numexpr` expressions are among the `e-TeX` extensions to the Knuth's `TeX`.

(e-TeX extensions: on modern installations they are activated by default, except if you use the executable named `tex` on the command line)

However you can't use truly fractional numbers inside `\numexpr...\relax` (for example doing `1/7+1/3`). And `/` does therein a (rounded) division to the nearest integer. Integers must be between `-2147483647` and `+2147483647`: this is the same limitation as for the integers one can store in a TeX `\count` or in a LaTeX `counter`; and a `\count` can be used directly inside a `\numexpr` expression, for a LaTeX `counter` one has `\value{mycountername}`.

I wrote package [xintexpr](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint) which can be used either in Plain TeX (`\input xintexpr.sty`)  or in LaTeX (`\usepackage{xintexpr}`).

1. if you want the final result rounded to an integer use `\xintiexpr`, for example `\xintiexpr 123456789987654321/(2^32+3^20)\relax`. Else `\xintexpr` will compute a fraction.
2. if you want the fraction in irreducible form, use the `reduce` function: `\xintexpr reduce (1/1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5+1/6+1/7+1/8+1/9+1/10)\relax`.
3. contrarily to `\numexpr` which can be used directly in places where TeX expect a (whole) number, for example in an `\ifnum` test, an `\xintiexpr` needs to be prefixed by `\xintthe`: `\xintthe\xintiexpr` (or `\xinttheiexpr`). But naturally, the produced number should be less than the `2^31` limit.
4. an `\xintthe\xintexpr` (or, shorter `\xinttheexpr`) can not be used in an `\ifnum` test, as TeX does not understand fractions. The package provides tests of its own to compare numbers incl. fractions.
5. an `\xintexpr` expression must be terminated by a `\relax` whereas a `\numexpr` will terminate legally on any token (like a dot `.`) not expected by its syntax.
6. `\numexpr -(1+2)\relax` does not work! but `\xintexpr -(1+2)\relax` does...
7. `\xintexpr` is completely expandable.

Hence things such as:

```
\message{\xinttheexpr reduce (1/1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5+1/6+1/7+1/8+1/9+1/10)\relax}
\message {\xinttheiexpr 123456789987654321/(2^32+3^20)\relax}
```

are possible.

Code for the OP use case:

```
\input xintexpr.sty\relax % compile with etex or pdftex

% macro to use \xinttheiexpr which will round to the nearest whole number.
\def\roundandprint #1{\xinttheiexpr #1\relax }

\def\weeks{20}          % term is twenty weeks
\def\lessonsperweek{3}  % meets three times per week
\def\lessonduration{60} % meets for sixty minutes

\def\percentlectures{.5}    % half the time is spent in lectures
\def\percentdiscussions{.2} % 20 percent of the time is spent in disucssions

% remaining percent of time left to lab work:
\def\percentlab{\xintexpr 1 - \percentdiscussions - \percentlectures\relax} 

% minutes spent in lessons:
\def\totalduration{\xintexpr \lessonduration * \lessonsperweek * \weeks\relax} 

% total duration in hours:
\def\totaldurationhours{\xintexpr \totalduration / 60 \relax}

% minutes spent in the lab:
\def\labduration{\xintexpr \totalduration * \percentlab \relax} 

Total time in lab: \roundandprint{\labduration} minutes.

Total minutes in class: \roundandprint{\totalduration} minutes.

Total hours in class: \roundandprint{\totaldurationhours} hours.

\def\weeks{19} % these two values are changed later in the document
\def\lessonsperweek{2}

Total minutes in class: \roundandprint{\totalduration} minutes. % this value
                                % would be different because of the chagnes to
                                % \weeks and \lessonsperweek

\bye
```

[image: add-subtract-multiply]

Remark: the various `\xintexpr ... \relax` in `\percentlab` etc... are a bit optional; they could have been replaced by parentheses, but using such `\xintexpr ... \relax` sub-expressions provides the maximal flexibility. For example, one can embed them in an `\edef`, naturally if everything involved in the computation is defined at that time.

As mentioned in a prior example the `^` for powers is accepted: but the exponent must be an integer (`3^(10/2)` is ok for `\xintexpr`, which will correctly compute `3^5`). There is a `sqrt` function, which computes the square-root with, by default, `16` digits of precision. A second optional argument allows more precision:

```
\xinttheexpr sqrt(2,60)\relax
```

gives `60` digits of precision.  To get the result in scientific notation, there is:

```
\xintthefloatexpr sqrt(2,60)\relax
```

Comment: I forgot to say that this answer does not use `\count` registers; and that it is provided in case you need to use (as in your mwe) stuff such as `0.2` or `0.5` which can not be used inside a `\numexpr`.

Answer (score 26):

plain tex (uniquely) is usually used with the classic Tex engine (or at least with pdf and e-tex extensions disabled) so there is no infix arithmetic

```
\newcount\zzz
\zzz=5
\multiply\zzz by 3
\advance\zzz by 2
```

sets `\zzz` to 17. If you use the plain format with e-tex you can use e-tex infix arithmentic

```
\newcount\zzz
\zzz=\numexpr 5*5 + 2\relax
```

Comment: @jfbu For assigning a value to a counter, there's no need of `\number` or `\the` in front of `\numexpr`. Actually, `\count255=\number\numexpr1+1\relax` could give you problems; try `\count255=\the\numexpr1+1\relax 1\showthe\count255` and `\count255=\numexpr1+1\relax 1\showthe\count255`

Answer (score 10):

You can use PGFmath.

For `\pgfmathprintnumber` from (`pgfmathfloat.code.tex`) it is necessary to define `\pgf@texdist@protect` for reasons unknown to me (this seems to be some protection mechanism).
Simply `\input`ting `pgf.tex` works, too.

### Code

```
\expandafter\def\csname pgf@texdist@protect\endcsname{}%
\input pgfmath.tex
\def\weeks{20}          % term is twenty weeks
\def\lessonsperweek{3}  % meets three times per week
\def\lessonduration{60} % meets for sixty minutes

\def\percentlectures{.5}    % half the time is spent in lectures
\def\percentdiscussions{.2} % 20 percent of the time is spent in disucssions
                            % remaining percent of time left to lab work
\def\percentlab{1 - \percentdiscussions - \percentlectures}
                            % minutes spent in lessons
\def\totalduration{\lessonduration * \lessonsperweek * \weeks}
\def\totaldurationhours{(\totalduration) / 60}
\def\labduration{(\totalduration) * (\percentlab)} % minutes spent in the lab

\pgfset{
  number format/.cd,
  min exponent for 1000 sep=4,
  int detect,
}
Total time in lab: \pgfmathprint{\labduration} (\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=0]{\pgfmathresult}) minutes.

Total minutes in class: \pgfmathprint{\totalduration}
                 (\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}) minutes.

Total hours in class: \pgfmathprint{\totaldurationhours} 
               (\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}) hours.

\def\weeks{19}         % these two values are changed later in the document
\def\lessonsperweek{2}
                       % minutes spent in lessons

% this value would be different because of the chagnes to \weeks and \lessonsperweek
Total minutes in class: \pgfmathprint{\totalduration}
                 (\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}) minutes.
\bye
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I upvoted, but have a question: as shown by the value for `\labduration`, `pgfmath` gives approximate values; does it provide a macro rounding to the nearest integer? (to pretty-print the result).

Comment: @jfbu As always, `pgfmath` uses simple TeX dimen calculation so the approximation is as precise as TeX gets it (with dimens and `\dimexpr`). Even though PGF also provides the `fpu` library we can use `\pgfmathprintnumber` to pretty-print numbers. Though the loading doesn’t seem as easy as I expected.

Comment: nice, thanks. I guess the `fpu` library has some `round` function and this is what you refer too (excuse my ignorance...)

Comment: @jfbu Not really: “The floating point unit (fpu) allows the full data range of scientific computing for use in PGF. Its core is the PGF math routines for mantissa operations, leading to a reasonable trade–of between speed and accuracy. It does not require any third–party packages or external programs.” It is heavily used by `pgfplots` and was written by the same author. The `fpu` library wouldn’t have these inaccurate results in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

If you are able to use latex, then you should consider the `sagetex` package, which gives you the power of a computer algebra system (CAS). It's using Python/Sage commands but since you're using such basic operations it will be easy for anyone to follow; easier than the code you wrote, I think, because Python is a high level language. I didn't see a calculation for `percenttests` so I set it to .3

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
weeks=20
lessonsperweek=3
lessonduration=60
percentlectures=.5
percentdiscussions=.2
percenttests=.3
percentlabs=1-percenttests-percentlectures
totalduration=lessonduration*lessonsperweek*weeks
totaldurationhours=totalduration/60
labduration=totalduration*percentlabs
\end{sagesilent}
\noindent Total time in lab: $\sage{labduration.n(digits=5)}$ minutes.
Total minutes in class: $\sage{totalduration.n(digits=5)}$.
Total hours in class: $\sage{totaldurationhours}$ hours.
\begin{sagesilent}
weeks = 19
lessonsperweek = 2
\end{sagesilent}
Total minutes in class: $\sage{totalduration}$ minutes.
\end{document}
```

The operations are done in the background using `sagesilent`. To access the calculations just insert `\sage` along with the calculation you wanted. You can control the digits displayed with adding .n(digits=5) or whatever you want. Previously, `sagetex` relied on having Sage installed on your computer. Now, with [Sagemath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/), you can run your LaTeX in the cloud and get access to Sage, too, without needing it installed on your computer. Screenshot of the the code running below:
[image]

Comment: `sagetex` is great, the OP asked for use with Plain: can one use `sagetex` with Plain or is it only for LaTeX?

Comment: the OP seems to want to have macros expanding to variable possible inputs, e.g. the `\weeks` macro; how does one go about feeding `sage` with such inputs?

Comment: It's for latex; I adjusted my answer to indicate that fact. The code above modifies `weeks` with the second sagesilent session modifying `weeks`.

Comment: Is this part of the standard distribution for TeX Live?  I don't seem to have `sagetex`.

Comment: [Sagetex is part of TeX Live](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/installation/sagetex.html) says "One potentially confusing issue is...TeXLive 2009 includes SageTeX. This may seem nice, but...it’s important...Sage bits and LaTeX bits be synchronized–which is a problem...since both Sage and SageTeX are updated frequently, and TeXLive is not.". In order to use sagetex you've needed (until Sagemath cloud) [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) installed on your computer. Since most people have an internet connection, no reason to limit yourself to plain Tex; you get Sage/sagetex functionality,too.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to subtract from a counter, use a negative value:

```
\newcount\h
\h 12
\advance\h -1
```