# Addition & Multiplication of parameter and constant with unit

Tags: calculations, parameters

I want to substract and multiply with an optional parameter and a constant with cm as unit. Like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage, xintexpr}

\newcommand{\test}[2][1]{
  \begin{adjustwidth}{(#1 -1)*0.8cm}{} %(#1 -1)*0.8cm
  %\begin{adjustwidth}{0.8}{}
    #2
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{0.8cm}{}
    Something else I need \#1 to be 1 at default
  \end{adjustwidth}
}
\begin{document}
  \noindent line1
  \test{Sampletext}
\end{document}
```

However `(#1 -1) * 0.8cm` isn't working.
I've already achieved `0.8cm * #1` by using `#1\dimexpr 0.8cm\relax`
But I'm unable to get both operations working.
How can I do this?

PS.: Already looked at [How to add, subtract, multiply, and divide in plain TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133317/how-to-add-subtract-multiply-and-divide-in-plain-tex#133326) but couldn't figure it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the e-LaTeX primitive `\dimexpr`. Note, however, that you need to do the multiplication in the correct order so instead of `\dimexpr(#1-1)*0.8cm` you need to use `\dimexpr0.8cm*(#1-1)`; see [formal syntax rules of \dimexpr \numexpr \glueexpr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245635/formal-syntax-rules-of-dimexpr-numexpr-glueexpr) for more details.

Here is a full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changepage, xintexpr}

\newcommand{\test}[2][1]{
  \begin{adjustwidth}{\the\dimexpr0.8cm*(#1-1)\relax}{} %(#1 -1)*0.8cm
    #2
  \end{adjustwidth}
  \begin{adjustwidth}{0.8cm}{}
    Something else I need \#1 to be 1 by default
  \end{adjustwidth}
}
\begin{document}
  \noindent line1
  \test{Sampletext}
  \test[6]{More sampletext}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]