# Help drawing as text a number from a formula (For instance [ 1-\thepage)*70+\i ] )

Tags: text-manipulation, tikz-path

Googling I found that it is common that `\lineno` does not work properly around `displaymath` with the `ifacconf.cls` template.

I am trying to improve a workaround I found for peer review reference. Specifically [THIS ONE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351984/package-lineno-not-working-well-skips-line-texlive-2016).

I would like to print the number result of the following operation `$(1-\thepage)*70+\i $` instead of just `\i`. Any clues?

See the minimal example which prints literally `"(1-"$\thepage$")*70+"$\i$`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AddEverypageHook{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \path (current page.north west) --  (current page.south west) \foreach \i in {1,...,\fakelinenos} { node [pos={(\i-.5)/\fakelinenos}, xshift=\fakelinenoshift, line number style] { $(1-\thepage)*70+\i $} }  ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\tikzset{%
  line numbers/.store in=\fakelinenos,
  line numbers=70,
  line number shift/.store in=\fakelinenoshift,
  line number shift=5mm,
  line number style/.style={text=gray},
}
\begin{document}
\section{problem (a), page 88}
\[
y^{\prime\prime}=\frac{1}{x^{5}}y
\]
Irregular singular point at $x\rightarrow0^{+}$.
Let $y=e^{S_{0}\left(x\right)}$ and the above becomes%
\begin{align*}
  y\left(  x\right)   &  =e^{S_{0}\left(  x\right)  }\\
  y^{\prime}\left(  x\right)   &  =S_{0}^{\prime}e^{S}\\
  y^{\prime\prime} &  =S_{0}^{\prime\prime}e^{S_{0}}+\left(  S_{0}^{\prime
  }\right)  ^{2}e^{S_{0}}\\
  &  =\left(  S_{0}^{\prime\prime}+\left(S_{0}^{\prime}\right) ^{2}\right)e^{S_{0}}
\end{align*}
Substituting back into $\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}y=x^{-5}y$ gives

Hence
\begin{align*}
  S_{1}  & \thicksim-\int\frac{S_{0}^{\prime\prime}}{S_{0}^{\prime}}dx\\
  & \thicksim-\ln S_{0}^{\prime}+c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to calculate a value you cannot just put the formula in the code, as you have seen. There are a few options to do calculations. Without packages you can use `\numexpr` (see for example [How to add, subtract, multiply, and divide in plain TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133317/how-to-add-subtract-multiply-and-divide-in-plain-tex)) or with packages you can use the [fp package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fp) or the [xint bundle](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xint), but given that you already use `tikz` you can use `\pgfmathparse` to perform calculations.

This macro performs the calculation in the argument and stores the result in the macro `\pgfmathresult`. You can use this macro to print the computed value. The calculation is floating point, so the result will have `.0` as a suffix for integers. You can use `\pgfmathprintnumber` to round the values.

For your calculation I expect you want continuous numbers for each page, i.e., page 1 has 1-70, page 2 has 71-140, etc. To accomplish this I have modified your calculation to be `\thepage-1` instead of `1-\thepage`. I have manually set the page number to 88 to show the result of the calculation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz,everypage}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \AddEverypageHook{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \path (current page.north west) --  (current page.south west) \foreach \i in {1,...,\fakelinenos} { node [pos={(\i-.5)/\fakelinenos}, xshift=\fakelinenoshift, line number style] { \pgfmathparse{(\thepage-1)*70+\i}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}} }  ;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  }%
}
\tikzset{%
  line numbers/.store in=\fakelinenos,
  line numbers=70,
  line number shift/.store in=\fakelinenoshift,
  line number shift=5mm,
  line number style/.style={text=gray},
}
\setcounter{page}{88} % set the page number manually
\begin{document}
\section{problem (a), page 88}
\[
y^{\prime\prime}=\frac{1}{x^{5}}y
\]
Irregular singular point at $x\rightarrow0^{+}$.
Let $y=e^{S_{0}\left(x\right)}$ and the above becomes%
\begin{align*}
  y\left(  x\right)   &  =e^{S_{0}\left(  x\right)  }\\
  y^{\prime}\left(  x\right)   &  =S_{0}^{\prime}e^{S}\\
  y^{\prime\prime} &  =S_{0}^{\prime\prime}e^{S_{0}}+\left(  S_{0}^{\prime
  }\right)  ^{2}e^{S_{0}}\\
  &  =\left(  S_{0}^{\prime\prime}+\left(S_{0}^{\prime}\right) ^{2}\right)e^{S_{0}}
\end{align*}
Substituting back into $\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}y=x^{-5}y$ gives

Hence
\begin{align*}
  S_{1}  & \thicksim-\int\frac{S_{0}^{\prime\prime}}{S_{0}^{\prime}}dx\\
  & \thicksim-\ln S_{0}^{\prime}+c
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that, and the documentation for \pgfmathparse solved it. I ended up using 
      \pgfmathparse{int((\thepage-1)*70+\i)} \pgfmathresult